# How to call Inline Table Function with output parameter from scalar function?

Tags: sql-server, function, sql-server-2000

I would like to know if it's possible to call a inline function with an output parameter from a scalar function?

For example:
My inline function is called test_1(input parameter format bigint), the following example works great:
**SELECT     * FROM         MM.test_1(4679)**

But now I would like to use it with an output parameter from a scalar function called dbo.test_2(output parameter format bigint) to make it more dynamically, but it don't works?
**SELECT     (SELECT * FROM MM.test_1(dbo.test_2(kp.id))) 
FROM         kp kp
WHERE     id = 4679**

I receive the following error message:
 
**"Error in list of function arguments: '.' not recognized.
Incomplete parameters list.
Missing FROM clause.
Unable to parse query text."**

Any suggestions?

Any help will be appreciated!

Thx forward,
Best Regards Andreas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can interpret what you're trying to do in two different ways.

#### Scenario 1:

You want to get a **single value** out of your **kp** table first, then run it through the static function, then feed the result to the inline function and get a table.

In this case, you can do something like:

```
declare @foo int;
set @foo = (select kp.id from kp where blahblahblah);
select * from MM.test_1(dbo.test_2(@foo))
```

#### Scenario 2:

More likely, for **each record** in your **kp** table, you want to do all those nasty things to its id and **union** the resulting tables.

In this case, the best I can suggest would be some dynamic SQL that goes through your id values, using a **cursor**, computes the partial results, then UNIONs it all together. Google for using cursors to loop through tables and you'll find enough to get you going (like [this post](http://justgeeks.blogspot.com/2008/08/using-t-sql-cursor-in-sql-server.html)). You must think of your table-valued function like a (surprise...) table. You cannot use it as a column in a SELECT statement in the same way you could use a static function and also you cannot feed the fields of a query back to themselves.

If you are calling this SQL from an application you should seriously think about doing this in code instead.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM MM.test_1(dbo.test_2(4679))
```

This part should work fine if you have a table-valued function **test_1** and a scalar function **test_2**. I can only test in MSSQL 2008 now, but as far as I know MSSQL 2000 should like it too.

How-eeever.. what do you expect your sample query to do? As far as I can tell you're selecting the output of **MM.test_1** *from* **kp**... which doesn't make sense.